# Integrating listings with fancyvrb

Tags: beamer, listings, fancyvrb

I am trying to use `fancyvrb` with `listings` and I get an error saying

> l.2 ...{Verbatim}[formatcom={\lstset{style=Java}}]
>
> Package Listings Error: language java undefined.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{bars}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\lstdefinestyle{Java}{ %
language=Java,                % choose the language of the code
basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, % the size of the fonts that are used
numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
numberstyle=\tiny,      % the size of the fonts that are used for
stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. 
numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular
frame=single,           % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,          % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=b,           % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,        % sets automatic line breaking
breakatwhitespace=false,   
%escapeinside={\%*}{*)},     % if you want to add a comment within your code
fancyvrb=true,
}




\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Listings with Fancyvrb}
  \begin{Verbatim}[formatcom={\lstset{style=Java}}]
    new Date(); 
  \end{Verbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the listings java language setting spelled with a capital J?

Comment: the first error I get from fancyvrb with the above, if `\FancyVerbGetLine` does not find a `^^M`, then we are at the end of the file,and `\FV@EOF` attempts to terminate the document. Otherwise, `\FV@EOF` is gobbled by `\FancyVerbGetLine`, according to the manual.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! dalief, Java is spelled with a capital J. The answer provided by Herbert and Jubobs of using /lstset{style=Java} before the \begin{lstlistings} works. I did not the first solution provided by Herbert, which is to define a new environment yet. But I will try it and post if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define your own environment or use explicitely `\lstset`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{bars}   
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\lstdefinestyle{Java}{%
language=Java,                % choose the language of the code
basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, % the size of the fonts that are used
keywordstyle=\bfseries,
numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
numberstyle=\tiny,      % the size of the fonts that are used for
stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. 
numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular
%frame=single,           % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,          % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=b,           % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,        % sets automatic line breaking
breakatwhitespace=false,   
%escapeinside={\%*}{*)},     % if you want to add a comment within your code
fancyvrb=true,
}

\newenvironment{JavaCode}
  { \VerbatimEnvironment%
    \lstset{style=Java}
    \begin{Verbatim} }
  { \end{Verbatim}  }  

\begin{document}

\begin{JavaCode}
import java.util.Vector;

abstract class Figur{
  abstract double getFlaeche();
}

class Rechteck extends Figur{
...
\end{JavaCode}



\lstset{style=Java}
\begin{Verbatim}
import java.util.Vector;

abstract class Figur{
  abstract double getFlaeche();
}

class Rechteck extends Figur{
...
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at subsection 4.15 *Interface to `fancyvrb`* in the `listings` documentation. You're supposed to set all the `listings` option with `\lstset` *before* the beginning of the verbatim environment used, *not* in an optional argument of the latter.

A tip: you should perhaps use a different style name than `Java`, to avoid confusion with the predefined `language` of the same name.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{bars}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\lstdefinestyle{Java}{ %
language=Java,                % choose the language of the code
basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, % the size of the fonts that are used
numbers=left,                   % where to put the line-numbers
numberstyle=\tiny,      % the size of the fonts that are used for
stepnumber=1,                   % the step between two line-numbers. 
numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false,         % underline spaces within strings
showtabs=false,                 % show tabs within strings adding particular
frame=single,           % adds a frame around the code
tabsize=2,          % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
captionpos=b,           % sets the caption-position to bottom
breaklines=true,        % sets automatic line breaking
breakatwhitespace=false,   
%escapeinside={\%*}{*)},     % if you want to add a comment within your code
fancyvrb=true,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Listings with Fancyvrb}
  \lstset{style=Java}
  \begin{Verbatim}
    new Date(); 
  \end{Verbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm wondering a bit here, what is the advantage to use fancyverb and listings inside fancyverb?

Comment: According to the subsection I quote from the doc, `fancyvrb` *provides macros for reading, writing and typesetting verbatim code. It has some remarkable features the `listings` package doesn’t have.* I haven't looked into it further.

Comment: I'd like to know what those features were...

Comment: Daleif, I believe you can use latex commands inside Verbatim environment and not inside lstlistings environment. I did not have much success with them though.

Comment: If you define escape sequences, then you can escape just fine I listings. I typically use a pair if X... X for that